# Object is immutable in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, compoundjs, jugglingdb

```
c.models.car.findOne where: {id: 1}, (err, car)->
    car['seat'] = 1  #seat is not originally in the car object but I would like to add it
    car['color'] = 'red'  #color is originally in car and is changed
    console.log car
```

The issue is that color is being changed, but seat is not being added.  When I do `typeof car` it returns `object`. Any ideas?

Comment: Was `seat` a car attribute, but not assigned, or was it not an attribute at all to begin with?

Comment: Is this a database query?

Comment: @Blender yes it is a db query

Comment: @zeantsoi seat was not an attribute at all to begin with. I want to add it. But it is not "sticking"

Comment: @Alexis: This isn't really a JavaScript question. It's an issue with your ORM, so tag it as such.

Comment: @Blender good call.  Done.  It is using jugglingdb and compoundjs.  But I still think it is a js issue because the ORM is returning the right thing - an object with the right results.  It seems like a js issue that I can't add a key to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using an ORM which decline the assignment. Try to use this:

```
c.models.car.findOne where: {id: 1}, (err, car)->
    car = car.toObject(); # or car = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(car))
    car['seat'] = 1  #seat is not originally in the car object but I would like to add it
    car['color'] = 'red'  #color is originally in car and is changed
    console.log car
```